# Skip a stage if the previous one has errors in Azure Pipeline Release

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I've got a very simple Azure Pipeline Release, I just want to skip a stage if there are any errors in the previous one. I've already checked https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic

Setting the Test job to run "Only when all previous jobs have succeeded" doesn't help

My main goal is to skip the test stage whenever there's a particular condition in the previous one, and passing variables between stages doesn't seem to be possible, nor using the gates, so I've got to idea to deliberately raise an error in the stage. The stages run some PS scripts, and I can't make the whole stage fail from that either

[Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s41X3.png)

Comment: If you're using logging command to raise the error, you need to add exit1 as Krzysztof Madej suggests. Also, this is documented [here](Krzysztof Madej).

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood you need sth like this [feature](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/374404/abort-on-error-in-pipeline.html). So as you see this is not supported out of the box.

You can use REST API to get state of running release and analyze response to verify it there is any issue with `issueType = Error`. Then in this script you need to call `exit 1`. This is not ideal, but it works.

```yaml
$uri = "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/thecodemanual/Devops manual/_apis/release/releases/$(Release.ReleaseId)?api-version=5.1"

Write-Host $(Release.ReleaseId)
Write-Host $uri

# Invoke the REST call
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Get -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"}


$errors = @()

$result.environments |
    ForEach-Object { $_.deploySteps | 
        ForEach-Object { $_.releaseDeployPhases |
            ForEach-Object { $_.deploymentJobs |
                ForEach-Object { $_.tasks |
                    ForEach-Object { $errors += $_.issues | Where-Object { $_.issueType -eq "Error" } }}}}}

Write-Host $errors.Count

if($errors.Count -gt 0) {
    Write-Host Error
    exit 1
}
```

Without step above I got this:

[image]

And with this step this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> The stages run some PS scripts, and I can't make the whole stage fail
>   from that either

Are you using PowerShell task or similar tasks? Try editing the task and enabling the `Fail on Standard Error` option:

[image]

After that task will fail if there's any error is written to the error pipeline. Also in pre-deployment conditions of your Test stage, make sure the `trigger when ...` checkbox is unchecked:

[image]

Comment: I tried `Fail on STandard Error` but it doesn't help. Task and whole stage were passing.

Comment: @KrzysztofMadej Hi friend, could you share some details about what your PS script(the one to throw the error) looks like? I'm trying to reproduce same issue and test it then on my side. ps: Voted for your answer cause I think it's meaningful.

Comment: I tried first to put `throw exception` or `exit 1` in my ps script. In both cases stage failed. So this was not an original case. After that I tried logging command `Write-Host "##vso[task.logissue type=error]Something went very wrong."` and in this case I got error reported without failing a task or stage. I know that this is probably not the same case as in the question. But at least I got the same behavior. After that I tried checking `Fail on Standard Error` and unchecking `Continue on Error`. But still build passed.

Comment: Got it, if the user got the error when using logging command, then he should always add an extra exit1 like what [the document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#example-log-an-error) states.

Comment: Yeah. I agree. But I have no idea if this actually happens in @DavideBonavita case. I used simply that to simulate behavior.